# Unable to write to root partition

Tags: filesystems, linux, ext4

For some reason, we are unable to write to my root ext4 partition. Unfortunately I don't have physical access to the computer, and I can't reboot or do anything because it's read only? How can we fix this? We're running ubuntu 10.04. The hard drive is an OCZ vertex

Here is a snippet of the error

```
[100337.752030] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 9579680
[100337.752097] sd 1:0:1:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[100337.752100] sd 1:0:1:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[100337.752104] sd 1:0:1:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 92 2c a0 00 00 08 00
```

Full error:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ttLM5ZkL

Comment: Your disk is toast.  Replace it.

Answer (score 4):

Paul says it all: your disk is toast (or maybe only your motherboard, or disk connector, or ...). Your filesystem is read-only because it automatically got remounted read-only due to the errors. You could try to cleanly shutdown by first remouting read-write with `mount -o remount,rw /` and then shutting down immediately. In any case, you'll most likely need to get your disk replaced.

Comment: Additionally, I'd make sure to do a full byte-for-byte copy of the drive to another known-good disk (doesn't have to be an SSD).

Comment: Or, failing a full disk image, backup the files while you can still read it.